# How to play audio via a USB sound card using c++/libao/alsa on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, arm

I get the following from `aplay -l, lsusb`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 0: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 0: ALSA [bcm2835 ALSA], device 1: bcm2835 ALSA [bcm2835 IEC958/HDMI]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Device [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Device_1 [USB PnP Sound Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0d8c:013c C-Media Electronics, Inc. CM108 Audio Controller
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 05e3:0606 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB 2.0 Hub / D-Link DUB-H4 USB 2.0 Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:0005 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I want to play my MP3 via CM108 Audio Controllers with libao. I tried these:

```
ao_initialize();
ao_option aoption;
ao_option *poption;
poption = &aoption;
poption->key = (char*)"dev";
poption->value = (char*)"hw:0";
dev = ao_open_live(driver, &format, poption); 
    while (mpg123_read(mh, buffer, buffer_size, &done) == MPG123_OK)
        ao_play(dev, (char *)buffer, done);
```

So sound is played via the Pi successfully. I understand that hw:0 is a sound card of the Pi. What should I use instead of hw:0 if I want to play via the first or second CM108 Audio Controller? I already tried hw:1 and hw:2 and it does not work.

Comment: Can you play wave file through aplay...try using this command   aplay -D 'hw:1' file.wav

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow below steps to enable audio recording and playback from a usb-sound adapter for rpi with alsa first. With this you can test your USB sound adapters are working correctly as input and output module.I have not tested before a usecase with above mentioned library in C++ code, will give it a try soon. Try by referring to "hw:1" later in your C++ code if it working.

Steps:
1.1) Create/edit file .asoundrc

```
$vim .asoundrc
```

If file is not present create it;

```
$ touch .asoundrc

$vim .asoundrc 
pcm.!default {
        type asym
        playback.pcm "hw:1,0"
        capture.pcm "hw:1,0"
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 1
}
```

1.2) Edit below line in file alsa.conf;

```
$sudo vim /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
defaults.ctl.card 0
defaults.pcm.card 0
```

to

```
$sudo vim /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf
defaults.ctl.card 1
defaults.pcm.card 1
```

1.3) Change audio levels/setting using alsamixer utility

```
$alsamixer
```

1.4) Command to record audio

```
$arecord -D plughw:1 -f S16_LE -r 48000 -d 5 ./testSound.wav
```

1.5) Command to play recorded audio

```
$aplay --device=plughw:1,0 ./testSound.wav
```